# Using icp algorithm in pcl

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to use the icp algorithm in pcl library, and have few questions:

1. should I generate the icp like that:

   ```
   pcl::IterativeClosestPoint <``pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> icp;
   ```

   or with

   ```
   pcl::PointXYZRGB.
   ```
2. the icp score in the end is 0.

Can I do something to help it success?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use the 1st option mentioned. It creates an instance of the iterative close point. To save the resultant cloud, you should use something like

   pcl::PointCloud Final;
2. A score of 0 means that the algorithm has converged.

Comment: that's mean that score = 0 is the good result? because it returns me score=0 but the all the points in the Final PointCloud are empty. what that means?

Comment: can we please post your code so that we can check if you have aligned it not.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can see an example code with explanation here:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/iterative_closest_point.php

```
pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> icp;
icp.setInputCloud(cloud_in);
icp.setInputTarget(cloud_out);
```

2. A low fitness score, like 0, is a good result, yes. Which can be interpreted as the remaining distance between the two point clouds you're trying to fit.

   2.1. A low fitness score doesn't necessarily mean that the icp converged (if the fitness score is 0 it obviously did though, since it is the optimum) for any other non optimal fitness score you can check whether the icp converged with this line of code:

   `icp.hasConverged() = 1 (true)`

Comment: Why did I get a downvote for this? Please let me know, so I can improve.